# How do SSH sessions work with iTerm?

Tags: macos, ssh, iterm

When I use PuTTY on Windows, if I SSH to some server and launch a script there, closing the PuTTY window stops the script. (so I typically use `screen` to avoid that)

When I use iTerm on Mac OS X, if I SSH to some server and launch a script there, closing the iTerm window doesn't stop the script. How comes?

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.

Comment: What's the exact version of your iTerm?